# How should I correctly handle an API Timeout in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, while-loop

**Background** -
I am writing a `.py` script that calls an API, saves the response as a `.json` file and performs various other tasks, before saving the response to a `.xlsx` file.

**Issue** -
The API I am calling is very unreliable, especially as it's a `GET` response with c.6000 rows of data, as demonstrated by the following intermittent timeout errors in the empty `.json` file (which should contain the response):

[image]

**Function that calls the API** -

```
def api_call():
        key, secret = ini_reader()
        date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        url = "https://myfirm.vendor_api.com/api/v1/portfolio/views/304078/results?portfolio_id=1&portfolio_type=firm&output_type=json&start_date="+date+"&end_date="+date+"&addepar_firm=381"
        print("-------------------------------------\n","API URL constructed for:", date, "\n-------------------------------------")
        response = requests.get(url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers={"Vendor-Firm":"461"})
        api_response = json.loads(response.text)
    return api_response
```

**Objective & proposed solution** -
I would like my script to continue to call the API until successful (successful = no errors). The only real solution I can think of is to implement a `while loop` in my script's function, which makes the API call.

Where I am stuck, is how I would define the condition to be met, in order that the script ends, and doesn't get stuck in a infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following -

1. Despite my API response intermittently giving me a `Error: 400: Bad Request - API request timeout exceeded.` the API response was still being written to a `.JSON` file and the response was still saved in a variable named `api_response` which I was trying to `pd.json_normalize` using.
2. A function named `def unpack_response():` (which is responsible for unpacking and normalizing the API response was the part of the code throwing up a `KeyError` when attempting to run, this was due to the `api_response` variable containing nothing.
3. I ultimately solved this issue by implementing a `while True` loop on the part of my code with `def unpack_response():` that utilized the `api_response` variable contents.

**Function with `while True` loop** -

```
def unpack_response():
    api_response = response_writer()

    while True:
        try:
            df = pd.json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])
            df.drop(columns=['grouping', 'entity_id'], inplace=True)
            df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'columns.', '')
            column_name_mapper = {column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in api_response['meta']['columns']}
            df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper, inplace=True)
        except KeyError:
                    print("-----------------------------------\n","API TIMEOUT ERROR: TRYING AGAIN...", "-----------------------------------\n")
                    api_response = reponse_writer()
        break
```